# scipy/numpy find the lower envelope of four functions

Tags: python, numpy

given four equations

ex.

```
2p + 4(1 − p)
3p+(1−p)
p+6(1−p)
5p
```

How would I find the lower envelope of the 4 functions where p is 0<=p<=1 . And then find the maximum of the points that make up the lower envelope.

[image: visual of what I mean]

I'm new to numpy and Scipy and am kind of lost as to how to do this. Not asking for an answer because this is homework just need a push in the right direction :) I've been googling for hours and can't find anything particularly useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll map out a dumb algorithm for you.  You can optimize and deal with boundary cases.

Find min at zero.  Find all intersection points, p1 .. pn.  Pick values between each intersection, q1..qn, where pi < qi < p(i+1).  Find the minimum value for the set of functions at q1..qn.

Construct your envelop to be a piecewise function from 0 -> p1 -> ... -> pn -> 1, where the line defining the envelope the the min at each value qi.